# Google Apps Script - Slides - replaceWithImage too slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm using Apps Script to generate slides containing tiles.
Each tile contain some information, example: name, ID and an image.

To generate each slide & each tile, I'm using a template composed of shapes, each shape to be modified contains a label such as {{label}}

When I find {{image}} shape, I replace the shape by an image.
Images are stored on Drive. I put everything in place to retrieve the blob associated to image but the single operation replaceWithImage takes around 2 seconds (I used console.time/timeEnd just before replaceWithImage and after).

Any idea how to accelerate this ? Initially I was suspecting the search on Drive, but it's around 200ms to look for the file and get the blob.